# R code to change the input format of file

Tags: r

I need the following #Input file (tab delimited) in a specific #output file format. I am trying to do this in R but somehow unable to get the right format. Any help will be appreciated.

## Input

```
ID  R1      
NAME    MASTER      
ATTR    Bed     
            
ID  R2      
NAME    OFFICE      
ATTR    Table       
ATTR    Chair       
            
ID  R3      
NAME    KITCHEN     
ATTR    Dishes
```

## Output

```
ID  NAME    ATTR    
R1  MASTER  Bed
R2  OFFICE  Table   Chair
R3  KITCHEN Dishes
```

Comment: Just so you know, tabs get stripped out when posting here.

Answer (score 1):

```
x = read.table(text = 'ID  R1      
NAME    MASTER      
ATTR    Bed     
            
ID  R2      
NAME    OFFICE      
ATTR    Table       
ATTR    Chair       
            
ID  R3      
NAME    KITCHEN     
ATTR    Dishes      ')

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

x %>%
  rename(name = V1, val = V2) %>%
  mutate(
    ID = ifelse(name == "ID", val, NA_character_)
  ) %>%
  fill(ID) %>%
  filter(name != "ID") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = val, values_fn = \(x) paste(x, collapse = "\t"))
# # A tibble: 3 × 3
#   ID    NAME    ATTR          
#   <chr> <chr>   <chr>         
# 1 R1    MASTER  "Bed"         
# 2 R2    OFFICE  "Table\tChair"
# 3 R3    KITCHEN "Dishes"
```

Comment: This is really a great help. Just a quick question, there should be three columns in the output - "ID"  "NAME"    "ATTR" (all tab delimited). May be I am missing something. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sorry about that - edited to get the three columns with tab separation.